# search from textarea

Tags: firefox, search

In Firefox I can select text and right click to search the selected text in the current search engine is use. This works only for static text; for example any text I select in the textarea (or whatever) box where I am writing this question in cannot be searched using the context menu. This can be done in Google Chrome.

Is there any add-on that makes this available?

Answer (score 2):

Besides other useful functionality, I found that the add-on [Context Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/context-search/) provides this as well.